# Where is the Git Bash `/` directory?

Tags: git-bash

When I open Git Bash on Windows 7, the default directory is `/`. It has *nix-style subdirectories, and `cd ..` doesn't change the directory. Where is this directory on my Windows machine?

The directory `C:\Program Files\Git\` has similar contents, except that `/` has a `proc` subdirectory, and `C:\Program Files\Git\` doesn't.

I put `dir /s /a git-bash.exe` in `cmd.exe`, and it only came up with the `git-bash.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Git`, no other one (such as the one in `/`).

Comment: Try running `mount` in the the bash shell.

Comment: Read https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/git-for-windows-tip-setting-home-and-the-startup-directory/ or http://shawnhymel.com/576/quick-tip-changing-default-directory-of-git-bash/

Comment: @LazyBadger OK so according to Git Bash Properties (I right-clicked on Git Bash), it starts in `C:\Program Files\Git\ `.  This still doesn't answer why `/` has a `proc` subdirectory and `C:\Program Files\Git\ ` doesn't.  Do you know?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, this also corroborates this.  `mount` gives the line: ```C:/Program Files/Git on / type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)```.  But why does `/` have a `proc` subdirectory that `C:\Program FIles\Git\ ` doesn't have then?

Comment: Again: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html "`/proc` is very special in that it is also a **virtual filesystem**. It's sometimes referred to as a process information pseudo-file system. **It doesn't contain 'real' files** but runtime system information (e.g. system memory, devices mounted, hardware configuration, etc)."

Answer (score 83):

In Git Bash, open Windows Explorer with this command:

```
explorer .
```

You will then see your current directory in the explorer address bar

Comment: excellent answer : simple and actually works for any folder. With this I discovered that /tmp was mounted for c:/users/[my winuser]/[local app data folder]/temp

Comment: Mine was at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2

Comment: On Windows 10: `C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\etc`

Answer (score 11):

You can run `cmd` from the current directory in Git Bash. That will start a windows `cmd` shell, which will show the windows path in the command prompt. Then type `exit` to return to Git Bash.

For example:

```
$ cmd
Microsoft Windows ...

C:\Program Files\Git>
```

(This is also a quick way to convert unix path to windows path.)

Comment: Do you have advice on the opposite conversion? I.e. I am having trouble navigating to some of the standard Windows paths on the Linux prompt (e.g. how do I cd to C:\Program Files ?)

Answer (score 4):

`cd / && pwd -W | sed 's/\//\\/g'`

```
$ echo "$(cd / && pwd -W | sed 's/\//\\/g')"
C:\Users\EXAMPLEUSER\Documents\PortableGit
```

---

Explanation:

Changing directory to root directory '/' will take you to where git was installed. The conventional "$PWD" variable won't provide much help as it says '/' too.
To get the true working directory, the command `pwd` followed by the `-W` argument is required

`-W  print the Win32 value of the physical directory`

This alone will print the correct and full directory, however it uses the Unix '/' separator between directories which Windows may not use system-wide, so the sed command edits the '/'s to '\'s

Answer (score 2):

Thank [@GaryBarrett](https://superuser.com/users/153874/gary-barrett) for [his/her nice hint](https://superuser.com/a/1407885/680152).

In git-bash:

```bsh
cd /bin
start .
```

Comment: What does `start` do? Explaining your answer would make it more useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you using [Far Manager](https://farmanager.com) it's possible to find an application/file by pressing Alt-F7 then `bash.exe` in the search field. Second, need to select the `Select search area` parameter to `In PATH Folders`[image].

This will be helpful if you accidentally install more bash installations than one.

Answer (score -1):

if on my computer with windows it is here: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`

or this is the default location `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\`

Comment: That doesn't make any sense unless you've modified the install. If you haven't modified your install / isn't where you think it is.